# how to use bcp in client system not remote

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

i want use bcp but i cant remote to data base
i use this command but i get error below:

> bcp "Select personelid, '13'+date date, scheduleid, scheduleGroupName,
>   DetailCollectionID, Name, TimesStructure, DayNO, Sequence, WPID,
>   ToleranceTimes, DayState, StructureID, ID, STime, ETime from
>   framework.att.PersonDateStructure" queryout "D:\test\pds.txt" -T -c -S
>   10.0.0.108 -U sa -P 0000

but i get this error:

> SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'KASRA\mnaghsh

Comment: Error seems pretty clear here, what about the error don't you understand so we can try to elaborate?

Comment: my system is in the domain.@Larnu

Comment: But clearly the login your using isnt a login on the server. The domain has nothing to do with that. Seems you don't understand the error. It's telling you that the windows login your using to connection to SQL Server (`KASRA\mnaghsh`) does not have a login on the server you are trying to connect to, the said login had been denied logon permissions, or it does not have a mapped user in the database you're providing in your connection string.

Comment: i should build login with this name(KASRA\mnaghsh) in sql?@Larnu

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I'm not sure what else I can explain here. The error is self explanatory, and I've expanded on it. If you don't understand any of that, the no suggest reading up on SQL Server and logins, as you're missing fundamental understanding about authentication.

Comment: "i should build login with this name(KASRA\mnaghsh) in sql?"...yes, you need to have a valid login in SQL Server which maps to that windows identity. As Larnu says, go and read about how logins work in SQL Server, so you understand properly what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You have specified the username&password (sa, 0000) using the -U -P flags but at the same time you have set the -T flag/argument which is for windows authentication, that is the reason you are getting the login failure message (apparently your domain account is not a valid sql server login), just remove the -T.

Comment: im removing -T but now i getting this error:
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Comment: output the data to a folder on the C drive:  ...queryout "C:\testXYZ\pds.txt"

Comment: i change ir but problem not fix.do you have any other idea?

Comment: do not specify a folder, queryout "pds.txt" and find/search for the file afterwards...